# How to assign the version of a specific PackageReference to a property

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to get the version of a specific package that is referenced through the `PackageReference`, so that I can reference a tool that comes inside one of those packages. I am able to write the version using a `Message` task:

```
<Message Importance="High" Text="@(PackageReference-&gt;%(PackageReference.Version))" Condition="'%(PackageReference.Identity)' == 'Google.Protobuf.Tools'" />
```

How can I retrieve that value inside a property?

The relevant parts from my csproj looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.5.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf.Tools" Version="3.5.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="1.8.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="1.8.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <ProtobufCompiler>$(UserProfile)/.nuget/packages/Google.Protobuf.Tools/3.5.0/tools/windows_x64/protoc.exe</ProtobufCompiler>
  <GrpcCSharpPlugin>$(UserProfile)/.nuget/packages/Grpc.Tools/1.8.0/tools/windows_x64/grpc_csharp_plugin.exe</GrpcCSharpPlugin>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can use the `CreateProperty` task for that:

```
<CreateProperty Value="%(PackageReference.Version)" Condition="%(PackageReference.Identity) == 'Google.Protobuf.Tools'">
  <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="GoogleProtobufToolsVersion" />
</CreateProperty>
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest Grps.Tools calls proto compiler during the build.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.31.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="my.proto" GrpcServices="None">
</Protobuf>
```